# how to implement a singleton - in weblogic

Tags: java, servlets, singleton, weblogic-10.x, servlet-filters

I tried implementing a singleton class method , which is invoked by a filter class.
The filter class and the rest of the classes , are added to WLS as a shared library.

And i have two separate web apps running -  servlets with filter - both on the same managed server.

So everything is working fine except , the singleton is getting instantiated twice .
plz find below the code snippet.

```
public class Test
{
   private static Test ref ;

   private DataSource X;  
   static int Y;
   long Z ;   


   private Test ()
   {
      // Singleton 
   Z= 100 ;
   }

   public static synchronized Test getinstance()  throws NamingException, SQLException
   {
      if(ref == null)
      {         
         ref = new Test() ;         
         InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();

         ref.X = (DataSource)ic.lookup ("jdbc/Views");
      } 
      return ref ;    
   }

   public Object clone()throws CloneNotSupportedException
   {
       throw new CloneNotSupportedException(); 
   }

   public int sampleMethod (int X) throws SQLException
   {
   }

}
```

Filter method:

```
public final class Filter implements Filter
{
 public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException
 {
  try
  {  
   Test ref = Test.getinstance();
   log.logNow(ref.toString());
   .......

  }
 }
}
```

In the log am getting two different references - say

*Test@f1a2e06    Test@f180f10*

Am i doing something wrong here ? Any help would be great.

Comment: Which version of WebLogic is this? The tag indicates 10.x, but that could be 10.0 or 10.3 or 11gR1 (10.3.x).

Comment: A singleton makes by the way no utter sense here. If you want a single instance per servlet context, use `ServletContextListener`. If you want a single instance per applicationserver, use JNDI as Bozho suggests.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A servlet container uses different classloaders for different application. So I don't believe it is possible to share an instance. What you can do is perhaps register the instance via JNDI.

Comment: Of course you can always have your singleton class in parent classloader(s) - e.g. in Container classpath - then it will be visible to all applications int he same Container and instantiated once. Though I won't recommend this approach for many reasons but if you have to have it then...

Comment: thanks for the replies . @ Bozho - I am kinda new to this . so could you point me in the right direction ? How do i Register the instance via JNDI ?

Comment: Hi Bozho,

I went through this . [http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11035_01/wls100/jndi/jndi.html#wp467275] .

Since i am new to this , am still not able to figure out what is meant by " register the instance via JNDI ".

So i have this java classes for filter etc .. now how do i register this ?  some code snippets ? examples may be ? TY

Comment: use the `bind` and `lookup` methods of the `Context` object.

Comment: I just came across a similar issue. JNDI look up does not seem to work if the object is binded in a different class loader, which is infact what is happening in two apps running in WebLogic